# Firestore (4.10.1): Could not reach Firestore backend. Firestore Access Issues In Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Quick question. Long story short, I am getting this error in my google cloud functions log:

Firestore (4.10.1): Could not reach Firestore backend.

Here is my code in my functions file:

```
 // pull in firebase
    const firebase = require('firebase');
    // required
    require("firebase/firestore");
    // initialize firebase
    const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
      // Firebase configuration.
        apiKey: "<Key Here>",
        authDomain: "<Auth Domain>",
        databaseURL: "<database url>",
        projectId: "<project id>",
        storageBucket: "<storage bucket>",
        messagingSenderId: "<messaging sender id>"
    });

    // setup the firestore
    var fs = firebaseApp.firestore();

exports.search = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  cors(request, response, () => {

    // set a reference to the foo table in firestore
          var docRef = fs.collection("foo");
          // check for the foo in the firestore
           docRef.where('bar', '==', <something>).get().then(function(doc) {
            if (!doc.docs) {
                return db.collection("foo").add({
                  bar: <something>
              })
              .then(function(docRef) {
                  console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
              })
              .catch(function(error) {
                  console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
              });
            }
          });
     });
 });
```

At this point I am stuck. As far as I can tell, I have things set up, but maybe not? I have searched the docs and googled the issue, without much success. Do you see anything wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All right. So the answer to my question is that I was not being very smart. A big thank you to Taha Azzabi for pointing me in the right direction. It turns out my problem was here:

```
docRef.where('bar', '==', <something>).get().then(function(doc) {
            if (!doc.docs) {
                return db.collection("foo").add({
                  bar: <something>
              })
```

This would never work. My query was correct, but the check on doc.docs was incorrect. My code is now:

```
// setup the firestore
      const fs = firebase.firestore();
      // set a reference to the document for the searched summoner
      var docRef = fs.collection("bars").doc("snickers");
      // check for the bar in the firestore
      return docRef.get()
      .then(function(doc) {
       if (!doc.docs) {
        return fs.collection("bars").doc("snickers").set({
          name: "snickers"
        })
        .then(function(reference) {
          console.log("Document written");
          return response.status(200).send('');
        })
```

This is what I was looking for so I am good to go. Long story short, I was grabbing a collection of results then trying to check to see if a single result existed. What I needed to do was grab a single doc from the firestore and from there check to see if the single doc existed. However, the error:

Firestore (4.10.1): Could not reach Firestore backend.

Didn't really do a very good job at pointing me in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the Firebase CLI ?

```
 npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Did you log in to the Firebase console through the CLI ?

```
firebase login
```

Did you initialize Firebase Cloud Functions ?

```
firebase init functions
```

You don't need then to reinitialize the app, initialize an admin app instance,thought. 
Here's an example hope that will help

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
//trigger a function to fire when new user document created
exports.createUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onCreate(event => {
        // perform desired operations ...
    });
```

to deployer your functions

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

read more here https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Comment: Thank you for your help! It pointed me in the right direction. I will point out that I am using the web implementation instead of node so the implementation you put above wouldn't have worked for my instance. However, I never specified that and that is my fault.